# How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using TypeScript/Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

```js
uploadWrapper($event)
  {
  console.log("Need the local computer path of file selected")
    }
```

```html
<input  type="file" (change)="filesPicked($event)" class="form-control" multiple>
```

I need the full path of the file when user selects a file from Choose File.

Comment: what you want to do with full image path? what is your needs?

Comment: @FarhatZaman I need to pass the file to httpPost which is present at the  local path(which needs to be extracted)

Comment: why you are not using buit-in plugins for file uploading. like `primeng`

Comment: @FarhatZaman in primeNg file uplaod also getting local path is not there..

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, for obvious security reasons, JS doesn't have access to the file system.

Comment: Thanks.Any other option?